# Infinite Scroll Pass Variable to hold SQL limit

Tags: php, jquery

I've got an jQuery infinite scroll running that appends 'load.php'.
load.php will have the SQL query to pull and echo the results.

However I'm stuck on how to pass a variable to determine where load.php adds the LIMIT to the SQL query. How can you pass a variable from a previous append of load.php and the new one, thus retrieving the next 10 records?

e.g.

- Append - Limit 10 (pass current limit)
- Append - Limit 20 (+ 10)
- Append - Limit 30 (+ 10)

Many Thanks

Comment: when u are querying from db u have to order it by some column so that
every time u send a limit u can get next 10 from that ordered data

Comment: I think I've just worked it out. Perform a PHP query on the main page, and just call msql_fetch_array (e.g. query['title']) in a while loop, and the while loop is determined by variables initialised on the main page - the load.php page requires no variables to be changed.

Comment: in that case every time u have to get all the records from db and run a while loop based on the variables